# How to debug "TypeError: Can't pickle objects in acquisition wrappers." in Plone

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

I have a handler that adds a Member to a Group. The last line in this handler causes an error:

```
TypeError: Can't pickle objects in acquisition wrappers.
> /home/mnieber/.buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/serialize.py(431)_dump()
    430         self._p.dump(classmeta)
--> 431         self._p.dump(state)
    432         self._file.truncate()
```

In the pdb debugger I can see that indeed Plone is trying to pickle a value that is an Acquisition wrapper:

```
ipdb> state
((((<PloneUser 'newuser@usecm.com'>, ('Default_Group',), 'maarten@usecm.com', ('PAS',)),),),)
ipdb> type(state[0][0][0][0])
<type 'Acquisition.ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper'>
```

However, I cannot see which object is being pickled, and therefore I have no idea which part of my code needs fixing. My question is: how should I go about debugging this error? I have tried looking at all the stack frames, but none of them reveal which object is being serialized.

The handler is this one (run_insecure is a decorator that I use to temporarily install a new security manager that avoids a NotAuthorized error when adding the new member):

```
@adapter(IPrincipalCreatedEvent)
@run_insecure
def userCreatedHandler(event):
portal_groups = getToolByName(getSite(), "portal_groups")
membersGroup = portal_groups.getGroupById('Default_Group')
membersGroup.addMember(event.principal)
```

The full error is this one:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 134, in publish
  Module Zope2.App.startup, line 301, in commit
  Module transaction._manager, line 89, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 329, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 443, in _commitResources
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 567, in commit
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 623, in _commit
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 658, in _store_objects
  Module ZODB.serialize, line 422, in serialize
  Module ZODB.serialize, line 431, in _dump
TypeError: Can't pickle objects in acquisition wrappers.
> /home/mnieber/.buildout/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.3-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/ZODB/serialize.py(431)_dump()
430         self._p.dump(classmeta)
--> 431         self._p.dump(state)
432         self._file.truncate()
```

Comment: I find a way to prevent the problem from happening (this provides no answer to my original question of what debugging approach could be used for the above error). The code to add a member to the group should be:


portal_groups = getToolByName(getSite(), "portal_groups")  
membersGroup = portal_groups.getGroupById('Default_Group')  
portal_groups.addPrincipalToGroup(event.principal.getId(), membersGroup.getId())

Answer (score 2):

I got this kind of problem with pickle, and solved by debugging like you did.

Pickle (used to store objects in ZODB) is trying to serialize your PloneUser, and raising this `acquisition wrapper` error.

In my case, I was wrapping the `portal_workflow` object into another `class`, and had to inherit it from `pickle.Pickler`, and override `__getstate__` method to solve my problem.

This method is called by pickle in order to serialize your object. If you override this method, and return your `object.__dict__` without this `PloneUser`, than this error would not be raised.

This [question](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/34502-why-cant-pickle-dump-instance) (although with not your exact problem) have more info about what I'm trying to  say.

Nice you could solve your problem.